# reconfigure the fstab file with UUID

Tags: linux, rhel, fstab, disk, lsblk

we have a lot of linux working machines

all mount point are configured in the /etc/fstab

as the following:

```
/dev/sdc /grd/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdd /grd/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdb /grd/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sde /grd/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdf /grd/sdf ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

I want to change the /etc/fstab configuration to use the UUID instead the current conf

can we reconfigure the fstab to use UUID , after machines are working for along time is OK ?

or maybe too late? , or risky ?

example:

```
 UUID="14314872-abd5-24e7-a850-db36fab2c6a1" /grd/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues. If you do changes to your machine configuration (for example add or replace disks) the device names (`/dev/sdX`) might change at next boot. Using UUIDs avoids this issue.

Since you use device names to name the mount points (`/grd/sdX`), those might not match the device name anymore should the  device names change for any reason.